# Odds of Winning a Raffle

Tags: probability

There's a raffle:

- 754 total entries in the raffle
- 130 will get selected

What's the odds that I will get selected?

### 2nd Question:

Now, what if I have 4 of the 754 entries? What are my odds then?

Can you walk me through the math on this?

Comment: Odds ... and my guess for the first part was 130/754.  I have no clue how to solve the 2nd part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  if you have multiple tickets, calculate the chance that you do not win and subtract from $1$.  What is the chance that your first ticket loses?  Given that it does, what is the chance that the next one loses-how many numbers are left?

Added:  to get the chance that you have two winners out of four, you have {6 \choose 2} ways to choose the winners, so the chance is ${6 \choose 2}\cdot \frac {130}{754}\cdot \frac {129}{753} \cdot \frac {624}{752} \cdot \frac {623}{751}$.  The others are similar.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**: How many different ways are there to choose $130$ of $754$ tickets?

If you have just one entry, then in how many ways can one of the chosen $130$ entries be yours and $9$ of them belong to other people?

If you have $4$ entries, then in how many ways can all $130$ chosen entries belong to someone else? How many ways, then, can at least one of your entries be chosen?